# Dojo/Dijit TitlePane (Basemap Gallery) Placement

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo, arcgis-js-api

I've been trying to place the Basemap Gallery **TitlePane** of this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_mic_/25rxc34k/1/) `code` on the right side of the mapDiv (center) pane, right next to the slider (marked as "BASEMAPS HERE").
I create a div called **switchPane** on the on the upper right corner of the pane and I would like for the TitlePane to go there (I initially thought "inside" the div but it doesn't seem to be working) and not on top of a Toggle Button for toggling the right pane on and off.
I could make an inline absolute placement (I tried with the relative but it didn't work) for the slider but I'm not able to do the same thing for the Basemaps Gallery TitlePane. I tried to change many CSS properties of the widjet but I'm getting lost not finding which one to override!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your fiddle and find out, that your class is overwritten by another one, so your Basemapgallery won't show up as expectet. Checkout my fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/e0k6Lfsa/8/
I setup a seperate clas for the tp and set the position attribute to important.

```
.tpclass { 
position:absolute !important;
top:10px !important;
right:40px !important;
}

var switchPane = domConstruct.toDom("<div id='switchPane' style='position: absolute; right:45px; top:2px; z-Index:999;'><strong>BASEMAPS HERE</strong></div>");
domConstruct.place(switchPane, "mapDiv");   

  var tp = new TitlePane({
    id: "tp",
    title:"Basemaps",
    closable: false,
    open: false,
    region:"mapDiv",
    class:"tpclass"
    },dom.byId("switchPane"));
```

It's iportant that you delete the //appLayout.addChild(tp); line, because of that, the class of the Titlepane is overwriten and thersfor your position right won't work.

Regards,Miriam

Comment: Hi Miriam, thanks a lot for your reply. Checking your fiddle (and changing my code) I realized that I can place the widget using the left property ONLY. When I try to set up the right property, it looks like the widget gets stuck on the pane left side, stretching itself to the set right value. Is there a way I can use the right property instead the left one to place the widget? Thanks again.

Comment: Hey mic! Onestly i have no experience in using position absolut and right. I just use left. After some google requests it might could be a problem with the position-styles of the parentnodes, but I'm nort sure about that.

Comment: The only use of left doesn't really help (opening the page in a screen with different resolution puts the widgets right in the middle of the page) and not to a define distance from the right side. What is the class you were talking about? Maybe importing dojo/dom-class and  remove that class? Or dojo/dom-geometry::position() to position the widget? (any difference from CSS, though?).. I have no idea! Thanks again.

Comment: Edited my post above, now it works. The class of the TP was overwritten by the appLayout and in consequence of that, position right can't work correct. Add the new fiddle

Comment: GREAT! it does work! I thought I had to add the widget to the main app! I think that there is also no need of style='position: absolute; right:45px; top:2px; z-Index:999; in the switchPane creation (the position is set in the tpclass CSS entry) and dom.byId("switchPane") when targeting the TitlePane div (it works with just the id "switchPane"). Thanks!